# Bloquear caracteres especiais mas permitir hífen

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Meu código para bloqueio de caracteres esta assim:

```js
 $('#nome').on('keypress', function() {
      var regex = new RegExp("^[ 0-9a-zA-Zàèìòùáéíóúâêîôûãõ\b]+$");
      var _this = this;
      // Curta pausa para esperar colar para completar
      setTimeout( function(){
          var texto = $(_this).val();
          if(!regex.test(texto))
          {
              $(_this).val(texto.substring(0, (texto.length-1)))
          }
      }, 100);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='nome'/>
```

Quero saber se há alguma forma de bloquear os caracteres especiais, porém permitindo a utilização de hífen (***-***)

Comment: Você quer, na verdade, permitir apenas alfanúmericos e o hifen, correto?

Comment: Não , ele tem que bloquear todos os caracteres especiais, exceto o Hifen

Comment: Sua regex diz o contrario, nela você está permitindo números, letras, letras com acento. Todos esse sao considerados alfanúméricos.

Comment: Sim , mas eu quero permitir o hifen também.

Comment: `^[ 0-9a-z\-A-Zàèìòùáéíóúâêîôûãõ\b]+$` vê se funciona.

Comment: Deu bom, o seu também :) @DiegoFelipe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta você fazer uma pequena alteração em seu `regex` permitindo isso. Seu 
`regex` ficaria assim:

```
RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9-Zàèìòùáéíóúâêîôûãõ\b]+$");
```

exemplo ficaria assim:

```js
 $('#nome').on('keypress', function() {
      var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9-Zàèìòùáéíóúâêîôûãõ\b]+$");
      var _this = this;
      // Curta pausa para esperar colar para completar
      setTimeout( function(){
          var texto = $(_this).val();
          if(!regex.test(texto))
          {
              $(_this).val(texto.substring(0, (texto.length-1)))
          }
      }, 100);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="nome"/>
```

Comment: Sem escapar o hifen?

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Como assim? A pergunta dele é para exatamente deixar somente o hifen.

Comment: Escapar o hifen na regex, assim: `^[ 0-9a-z\-A-Zàèìòùáéíóúâêîôûãõ\b]+$`

Comment: Foi resolvido o problema , 
Obrigado ai @Randrade

Answer (score 3):

adicione o hífen como último caractere de classe, dessa maneira não é necessário escapá-lo:

```
new RegExp("^[ 0-9a-zA-Zàèìòùáéíóúâêîôûãõ\b-]+$");
```

---

O seu código só remove o último caractere do campo, isso será um problema se for colado um texto com caracteres inválidos. O ideal é remover todos os caracteres inválidos com uma classe negada, que começa com um circunflexo (e.g. `[^a-z]`).

Outra melhoria que eu sugiro é utilizar o evento [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/input) que funciona melhor do que `keypress` para conteúdo colado.

```js
$(function(){
  var regex = new RegExp('[^ 0-9a-zA-Zàèìòùáéíóúâêîôûãõ\b-]', 'g');
  // repare a flag "g" de global, para substituir todas as ocorrências
  $('input').bind('input', function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(regex, ''));
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"/>
```